# sort&compress citations latex

Tags: bibliographies

everyone!

I've been searching for this topic for too long, so I'm asking it here.

I need to create a citation in my article by compressing numbers that goes with authors.

For example:

```
Blah-blah-blah~\cite{kerchev-paz} blah-blah-blah.....
```

and I have `\begin{thebibliography}{4}`:

```
 \bibitem{kerchev} Kerchev
\bibitem{chernova} Chernova
\bibitem{krivetz} Krivetz
\bibitem{paz} Paz
```

I need to latex this code into  `Blah-blah-blah [1-4] blah-blah-blah.....`

After including `\usepackage{cite}` I've got something like this `Blah-blah-blah [??] blah-blah-blah.....`

I need an emergent help =)

Comment: P.S. I use WinEdt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `\cite{<key>}`, the `<key>` has to match something that is in your bibliography *exactly* (or be separated by a comma). In your case the keys are `kerchev`, `chernova`, `krivetz` and `paz`, yet you request `kerchev-paz` which doesn't exist (hence the resulting [**?**]).

If you wish to have a sorted & compressed citation, you need to specify each of the keys involved in the citation and let BibTeX and LaTeX do the rest. So, you need to specify/list

```
\cite{kerchev, chernova, krivetz, paz}
```

The above order doesn't matter, just as long as they're all there.

The following minimal example highlights this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% For this example, create a bibliography
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kerchev, author={Kerchev}, title={Article 1}}
@article{chernova, author={Chernova}, title={Article 2}}
@article{krivetz, author={Krivetz}, title={Article 3}}
@article{paz, author={Paz}, title={Article 4}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{cite}% Default is to sort and compress

\begin{document}
\cite{kerchev,chernova,paz,krivetz}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The compilation sequence is (pdf)LaTeX > BibTeX > (pdf)LaTeX > (pdf)LaTeX.

Comment: thanx a lot! Now I wont have any problems with my future papers =) 

I have one more quastion left... On one of the pages text goes over namberpage and to the bottom of the page. It is very strange, because other pages are just fine. I've tried to insert `\pagebreak` and it works, but the number of the page missing...

Comment: @Ksenia: One would need to be able to replicate the problem in order to fully address the cause. Can you provide the [tex.se] community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: I've already solve the problem by editing my tex file properly.. compiling a few times helped =)